# Images uploaded from androids showing up sideways only on android device

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, mobile, file-upload

I have an image hosting website (written in Vue.js and stored in firebase) where users upload images and post a caption.

On desktop, iOS devices, and mobile view in devtools the images show up just fine (images #1 and #2 below).

However, on Android devices (Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 and another cheap phone) and Android emulators (Pixel 3a), the images show up sideways (image #3 below).

Weirdly, it's only the case for images that have been uploaded from those Android devices. All other images show up as intended.

[image: devtools]

[image: desktop]

[image: Pixel 3a emulator]

Answer (score 1):

Yes because some photos are taken orizontally and metadata is added to instruct the client how to rotate when presented. So, one solution would be to rotate the image and remove the metadata before uploading or leave the metadata and change the code in the client so that it first reads the metadata for rotation (EXIF) and than shows the image after rotation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface#TAG_ORIENTATION